# Summer Camp TextMate theme

Tags: textmate, themes

A while back on the User Submitted Themes wiki page on the TextMate site there was a link to the theme "Summer Camp", the entry is still there but the link no longer works.

I'm wondering if anyone has this theme and is willing to share?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it. Here's a copy of [Summer Camp](http://mipadi.cbstaff.com/documents/textmate/summer-camp.zip). I've also posted my derivative theme, [Summer Sun](http://mipadi.cbstaff.com/documents/textmate/summer-sun.zip), which includes wider support (I found that Summer Camp didn't have definitions for all the scopes I commonly used).